# Opencart products array

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to manipulate some data in opencart but am having some trouble. How would I go about checking this array for each key of $product['price'] to get smallest existing number and a true/false boolean if all numbers are the same. I am trying to do this with a foreach loop, but can't figure out what to do. Here is a rough idea of what I want.

```
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {

if($product['price'] == false){ //not the same
Smallest number of $product['price']
}else{
do something else
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions for that problem depending on what you need as an output. Here are two of them:

**Solution 1**

Get the lowest price (a number):

```
$prices = array();
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
  array_push($prices, $product['price']);
}
return min($prices); // return or do w/e with the lowest price
```

Check if all values are the same (`True` if all are the same, `False` if not):

```
return count(array_unique($prices) == 1);
```

What we do here is counting the number of unique entries ([array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) removes all duplicates) and check if it's equal to 1 (= all are the same).

**Solution 2**

Get the product (object) with the lowest price:

```
$prices = array(); // necessary for the "all equals check"
foreach($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
  if(!isset($cheapestProduct) || $cheapestProduct['price'] > $product['price']) {
    $cheapestProduct = $product;
  }
  array_push($prices, $product['price']); // necessary for the "all equals check"
}
return $cheapestProduct;
```

Check if all values are the same (if you're not going to need this, you can remove the two commented lines above):

```
return count(array_unique($prices) == 1);
```